# Plot dates on X in Matplotlib from raw numbers

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot information I gathered in the list. It's simply statistic from chat of how many messages was sent each day by user. I'm having problem with transferring dates from my data to X axis on plot. It keeps showing as normal numbers.

```
list_of_records = [record1, record2, record3, ...]
```

where:

```
record = ['name', messages number, day, month, year]
```

Example of real data:

```
list_of_records = [['F', 2, 23, 9, 2018], ['A', 1, 23, 9, 2018], ['F', 2, 3, 7, 2018], 
['A', 2, 3, 7, 2018], ['A', 2, 3, 7, 2018], ['F', 2, 3, 7, 2018], ['F', 2, 3, 7, 2018]
```

Now I was looking at:[link1](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.num2date), [link1](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_demo_rrule.html#sphx-glr-gallery-ticks-and-spines-date-demo-rrule-p), [link1](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html), [link1](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html)

But non of it made a lot of sense to me, as they always import data from somewhere.

I'm guessing I have to import some kind of lib from matplotlib to convert number I will pull from the array to plot-friendly format of dates. Then use other sub library to plot it with dates. But how to do it? I have no clue.

It's my first time with matplot lib, so please don't be too generic in answers.

My code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

list = [['F', 2, 23, 9, 2018], ['A', 1, 23, 9, 2018], ['F', 2, 3, 7, 2018], ['A', 2, 3, 7, 2018], ['A', 2, 3, 7, 2018], ['F', 2, 3, 7, 2018], ['F', 2, 3, 7, 2018], ['F', 2, 3, 7, 2018], ['A', 2, 3, 7, 2018], ['F', 2, 3, 7, 2018], ['A', 2, 3, 7, 2018], ['F', 2, 3, 7, 2018]]

plot_x_A = []
plot_y_A = []
plot_x_F = []
plot_y_F = []

for value in list:
    if value[0] == "F":
        plot_x_F.append((value[-1],value[-2],value[-3])) 
        #X value - take year, month and day and pack in in tuple
        plot_y_F.append(value[1])                        
        #Y value - just number
    if value[0] == "A":
        plot_x_A.append((value[-1],value[-2],value[-3]))
        plot_y_A.append(value[1])

#print(plot_x_A)                 #double check myself if it looks all right
#print(plot_y_A)

plt.plot_date(plot_x_A,plot_y_A,xdate=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It looks like changing appended values from int to string helped. I will make more test and hopefully close the case.

        new_x = str([value[-1],value[-2],value[-3]])
        plot_x_F.append(new_x)

Comment: Use strings if you want categoricals, i.e. if each date is its own category like "Apple", "Banana" etc. Use `datetime` if you want your dates to be real dates, i.e. if you want to have double the spacing on the axes between the 12th and the 6th of a month compared to the 6th and the 3rd.